# Received null in Response when using volley to send ArryList to server

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-volley

I tried send an arraylist to server by volley,but I received null in my response method
I make ArrayList with this code:

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < questions.size(); i++) {

            //addToServer(questions.get(i),questions.size());

            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("TestId", questions.get(i).getTestId() + "");
            params.put("Number", questions.get(i).getNumber() + "");

            arrayList.add(params);
             }

        listOfQ = new JSONArray(arrayList);
```

and send It to server by this code :

```
public void addToServer2() {

    if(requestQueue == null){
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(myContext);

    }
    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ServiceApi.URL_send_question2, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("test", listOfQ.toString());
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return super.getHeaders();
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

and here is my php code that get arraylist and back one value to android side:

```
$arr = array();
$jsonarray = array();


$json = $_POST['test'];
$jsonarray = json_decode($json,true);

foreach((array) $jsonarray as $key){

     $TestId = $key["TestId"];
     $arr[] = array('id' => $TestId);
 }
```

when i debug my application it show me this in response : id:null

Comment: What is `listOfQ`? Is it JsonArray?

Comment: yes i converted it to JsonArray

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made some mistakes.
Try in this way,
1. Create a JSON Object.
2. Create a JSON Array and store all list data into it using for loop.
3. Store your JSON Array into a JSON Object.(After for loop ends).
4. As you will need to send this data in json type but in String Body format so
`String requestBody=your_json_object.toString()`.
5. When you use `StringRequest`, you have to send url in string format and the response will be a string format.
6. after error listener you will need to add these lines,  (In one curly brackets)

```
{
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }


        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

7. Below this method, you will need to add header parameters for authentication purpose.

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    headers.put("Authorization", "sometoken_or_id");
    return headers;
}
```

8. `requestQueue.add(request);`
9. Done

Comment: thanks for your answer, how can i Store my JSON Array into a JSON Object? i use myObject.put("test",myJArray) but i have this error: value null of type org.json.jsonobject$1 can not be converted to jsonarray